# matplotlib: change timestamp format of x-grid in a bar-chart

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have the following code:

```
 my_df.plot(x='my_timestamp', y='data_count', kind='bar')
```

and the output looks like this:

[image]

I am wondering is it possible to change the x-grid format, so it will just show `2016-03-14` instead of `2016-03-14 00:00:00`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a more elegant solution, but what definitely works is to loop over the xticklabels, split them up and only use the first part of the string as a new ticklabel.

```
ax = df.plot(x='my_timestamp', y='data_count', kind='bar')

ax.set_xticklabels([t.get_text().split(" ")[0] for t in ax.get_xticklabels()])
```