# Histogram per hour

Tags: python, matplotlib, group-by, histogram

I'm analyzing public data on transport accidents in the UK.

My dataframe looks like this :

```
Index     Time

0         02:30
1         00:37
2         01:25
3         09:15
4         07:53
5         09:29
6         08:53
7         10:05
```

I'm trying to plot a histogram showing accident distribution by time of day,
here is my code :

```
  import matplotlib
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  import numpy as np
  import datetime as dt
  import matplotlib.dates as mdates
  df['hour']=pd.to_datetime(df['Time'],format='%H:%M')
  df.set_index('hour', drop=False, inplace=True)
  df['hour'].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='60Min')).count().plot(kind='bar', color='b')
```

This is the output:

[image: Graph]

In this graph, I'd like to change the labels on the x-axis to the format 'hh:mm'. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Same as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42145062/matplotlib-change-timestamp-format-of-x-grid-in-a-bar-chart) you would just keep the other half of the strings.

Comment: @mostafazh, thank you for your answer. Your answer works but x-axis appeared like https://imgur.com/a/0gBB7KJ  . So x-axis is not indexed (I was looking for x-axis like that 01:00h, 02:00h, 03:00, ..)

Comment: No, I'd like that x-axis was indexed by time (01:00, 02:00, 03:00 ..instead of 02:30, 00:30, 01:25).

Comment: @mostafazh, my problem is that I want to plot data grouped by hour. I was doing it right in my first solution. The only problem was the datatime format. I needed 01:00 instead of 01/01/1900 01:00

Comment: @mostafazh, thank you!! It works fine now, had some problem plotting in Jupyter. I just started programming with Python. Any suggestions about a good IDE? I'm using Jupyter but not totally satisfied. I'm looking for something interactive.

Comment: I'd suggest PyCharm or if you want something fast then give vscode a try.

Comment: Thanks!! I'll try PyCharm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are missing is setting the format of the matplotlib x-axis format:

```
df.set_index('hour', drop=False, inplace=True)
df = df['hour'].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='60Min')).count()
ax = df.plot(kind='bar', color='b')
ticklabels = df.index.strftime('%H:%Mh')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FixedFormatter(ticklabels))
plt.show()
```