# Plotting DataFrames containing HH:MM format in a single figure matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

My question (written at the end below) is related to plotting histograms of two DataFrames in different sub-figures (**Situation 1 below**) as compared to plotting them in the same figure (**Situation 2 below**). The histograms are plotted taking an interval of 1 hour as the grouping criteria. Both the DataFrames have a single column with times in `"HH:MM"` format.

```
# Defining the two DataFrames
df_in = pd.DataFrame({'time': ['12:20', '12:06', '11:30', '11:03', '10:44', '10:50', '11:52', 
                               '12:21', '9:58', '12:43','12:56', '13:27', '12:14',]})

df_out = pd.DataFrame({'time': ['19:40', '19:44', '19:21', '20:37', '20:27', '18:46', '19:42', 
                                '18:12', '19:08', '21:09', '18:37', '20:34', '20:15']})
```

---

**Situation 1**: Plotting both DataFrames in different sub-figures

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FixedFormatter

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(9, 3))

colors = ['r', 'b']
titles = ['df-in', 'df-out']

# Looping over the dataframes and plotting them in subfigures
for df, ax, c, t in zip([df_in, df_out], axes.flatten(), colors, titles):
    df['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%H:%M')
    df.set_index('hour', drop=False, inplace=True)
    df = df['hour'].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='60Min')).count()
    df.plot(kind='bar', color=c, ax=ax)
    ticklabels = df.index.strftime('%H:%Mh')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FixedFormatter(ticklabels))
    ax.set_title(t, fontsize=18)
plt.show()
```

**Output of Situation 1**

[image]

---

**Situation 2**: Plotting both DataFrames in the same figure

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 3))

# Looping over the dataframes and plotting them in subfigures
for df, c, t in zip([df_in, df_out], colors, titles):
    df['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%H:%M')
    df.set_index('hour', drop=False, inplace=True)
    df = df['hour'].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='60Min')).count()
    df.plot(kind='bar', color=c, ax=axes)
    ticklabels = df.index.strftime('%H:%Mh')
    axes.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FixedFormatter(ticklabels))
plt.show()
```

**Output of Situation 2**

[image]

In both the cases, the code for formatting of strings is taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53244590/histogram-per-hour-matplotlib) question. As you can see, the red and blue Histograms have respective maxima at 12:00 and 19:00 h when plotted separately. But when I plot them in the same plot, the two histograms are overlapping and the maxima are not at 12:00 and 19:00 h. The problem seems to be trivial but I am not sure what is going wrong.

---

**My question is**: What needs to be modified in **Situation 2** to have both the histograms well separated and distinguishable (instead of overlapping) as they are centered clearly around 12:00 and 19:00 h? Any pointers and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You're plotting a categorical bar plot. In terms of matplotlib axis units the first "histogram" has its peak at positon 3, the second at position 1. Do you want to have a numeric axis instead where numbers represent real time instead of categories?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Thanks for your comment. Yes, I would like the x-axis to behave as a numeric axis. Basically I want both the subplots merged on the same figure where both the histograms are well separated and the x-axis goes from around 7:00 up to 23:00 h. I have achieved this by using `range(24)` for the x-axis, plotting **bar charts** instead of histogram and then re-labeling the x-axis labels to be `HH:MM`. But this is an ugly hack and I am sure there is a better direct solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A numeric bar plot could look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
register_matplotlib_converters()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import HourLocator, DateFormatter


# Defining the two DataFrames
df_in = pd.DataFrame({'time': ['12:20', '12:06', '11:30', '11:03', '10:44', '10:50', '11:52', 
                               '12:21', '9:58', '12:43','12:56', '13:27', '12:14',]})

df_out = pd.DataFrame({'time': ['19:40', '19:44', '19:21', '20:37', '20:27', '18:46', '19:42', 
                                '18:12', '19:08', '21:09', '18:37', '20:34', '20:15']})

colors = ['r', 'b']
titles = ['df-in', 'df-out']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 3))


for df, c, t in zip([df_in, df_out], colors, titles):
    df['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%H:%M')
    df.set_index('hour', drop=False, inplace=True)
    df = df['hour'].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='60Min')).count()
    df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
    ax.bar(df.index, df.values, width=1/24/2, color=c, label=t)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(HourLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter("%H:%Mh"))
ax.set_xlim(pd.to_datetime(["1900-01-01 07:00", "1900-01-01 23:00"]))
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Depending on the pandas version, it will throw a warning when not explicitely registering or deregistering a converter for pandas dates. See [this comment](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/11391#issuecomment-464073788) and others in that thread.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `sns`'s powerful hue:

```
# convert to time
df_in.time = pd.to_datetime(df_in.time)
df_out.time = pd.to_datetime(df_out.time)

# mark the series/dataframe and join
df_in['df'] = 'df_in'
df_out['df'] = 'df_out'
df = pd.concat((df_in,df_out))

# groupby hours:
df = df.groupby(['df',df.time.dt.hour]).size().reset_index()

# plot with sns
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
sns.barplot(x='time', 
            y=0,
            hue='df', 
            dodge=False,
            data=df)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

---

Edit: to plot the bars with x-axis being from 7 to 23, we can `reindex` before plot:

```
df = (df.groupby(['df', df.time.dt.hour]).size()
        .reset_index(level=0).reindex(range(7,24))
        .reset_index()
     )
```

And the `sns` barplot gives:

[image]

Comment: In the comments OP mentions "Basically I want both the subplots merged on the same figure where both the histograms **are well separated** and the x-axis goes **from around 7:00 up to 23:00 h**".

Comment: Thanks for the answer Quang. But I was looking for what @ImportanceOfBeingErnest answered.

Comment: I think the approach here is in principle good, it would just need to take into account all the possible categories (hours). So maybe it can be updated in this respect?